# How to prevent form submit when choosing a file with <input type="file>?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, preventdefault, html-input

I have a file input on my page:

```
<input type="file" id="file-main" style="display:none;" name="file-main">
```

And I have a lable pointing to that input:

```
<button class="main-button" id="file-choose-btn"><lable for="file-main">Choose Image</lable></button>
```

But when I press the button (to choose the file), the form immediately gets submitted, and tries to execute the PHP file (that's in the form's "action"). 
I do not yet have that file, so it returns a HTTP 404 error.

Basically, my question is, how do I prevent the form from being executed after clicking the  (or a button in this case).

I've tried using an event handler that prevents the default action of the event:

```
document.getElementById("file-choose-btn").onclick = function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
}
```

But then I cannot even choose the file, since the window doesn't even open.

Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Try to prevent default on the "onsubmit" event

Comment: @Chris Frank the "onsubmit" event on what? The form? Do I just target the form with the id?

Comment: I usually target the form id

Comment: That works, thanks! But now I cannot submit my form in any way. Can I remove event handlers in javascript? Because I want the handler to be removed after the user chooses the file. @Chris Frank

Comment: why do you need the button here? all your problems come from `button` element which is absolutely unnessessary as long as the action is performed by the `label`. Just change the button to be `<div>` or style your label instead

Comment: @aCodingN00b use a conditional statement statement to check if the user has chosen a file. If not then allow the form to be submitted.

Comment: @Chris Frank How do I check if the user has chosen a file?

Comment: @aCodingN00b `document.getElementById("yourForm").value != ""`

Comment: @smnbbrv I used the button just because it's already styled. The defualt input's button looks ugly. I forgot about the possibility to style the label to look like a button. Anyways, dfsq's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make button type `button` so it will not submit a form:

```
<button type="button" class="main-button" id="file-choose-btn">
    <lable for="file-main">Choose Image</lable>
</button>
```

By default button has type `submit` so hence the behaviour you get.